# Eigenvalues and Cayley-Hamilton theorem

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors

> Let $A$ be an invertible matrix such that $A^{-1}=I-A$.
>   Show that $A$ doesn't have real eigenvalues.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since 
$$A^{-1}=I-A$$
then we have
$$A^2-A+I=0$$
hence the polynomial $P(x)=x^2-x+1$ annihilates the matrix $A$ and then the eigenvalues of $A$ belong to the set of roots of $P$ which are  complex non real since the discriminant of $P$ is $\Delta=-3<0$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $\lambda$ be any eigen value. Then $\lambda\neq 0$ since $A$ is invertible. 
Now, using the following facts:

1. $\frac1\lambda$ is eigenvalue for $A^{-1}$.
2. $1-\lambda$ is eigen value of $I-A$.

I'm sure in this point you can finish by yourself, can't you?

Comment: Yea I did. thankyou

Answer (score 1):

If $A$ had an eigenvector $v$ for $\lambda$ (which eigenvalue cannot be $0$ since $A^{-1}$ exists), applying both sides of the euqation to $v$ would give
$$
  \lambda^{-1}v=v-\lambda v
$$
and since $v\neq 0$ for an eigenvector, this requires 
$$
  \lambda^{-1}=1-\lambda
$$
to hold. But that equation has no solutions for $\lambda$ in the real numbers, as you can easily check.